# Illegal character 0x0 when trying to delete more than 200 rows

Tags: soap-api, php-toolkit

I'm using salesforce's PHP SOAP client (SforceBaseClient) to attempt to delete records.  It's working fine for less than 200 at a time, and I remember reading that you are limited to 200 rows at a time.

So, in a flash of imagined brilliance, I created a loop to step through batches of 200 records.  The first batch works fine.  But when it loops and tries to delete the second batch, I get the "Illegal character 0x0" error.

Later, I realized that the `delete()` method in the SF SOAP client does exactly the same thing:

```
/**
 * Deletes one or more new individual objects to your organization's data.
 *
 * @param array $ids    Array of fields
 * @return DeleteResult
 */
public function delete($ids) {
  $this->setHeaders("delete");
  if(count($ids) > 200) {
    $result = array();
    $chunked_ids = array_chunk($ids, 200);
    foreach($chunked_ids as $cids) {
      $arg = new stdClass;
      $arg->ids = $cids;
      $result = array_merge($result, $this->sforce->delete($arg)->result);
    }
  } else {
    $arg = new stdClass;
    $arg->ids = $ids;
    $result = $this->sforce->delete($arg)->result;
  }
  return $result;
}
```

This should make it far easier; all I should have to do is call this method and pass it the complete array of IDs that I want to delete.  Right?

...Except it gives me the very same error after processing 200 records.

Has anybody run into this and have a solution?

---

Clarification -- This has nothing to do with record #201; if I call this method twice with only 1 record, it fails on the second call.

Answer (score 0):

The illegal character is a `null` response.

The issue is that for some reason my production environment keeps losing the soap connectivity.  Each call to a SOAP method seems to log out.

My temporary solution is to chunk the data and connect/log in on each iteration.